# gram-schmidt (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Consider $A = [a_1, a_2, a_3] = 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\\
        1 & -1 & 0 \\\       
        2 & 0 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

a) From the vectors $a_1, a_2, a_3$ find orthogonal vectors $q_1, q_2, q_3$ by Gram-Schmidt

b) Find the upper triangular matrix $R$ such that $A = QR$ with $Q = [q_1 q_2 q_3]$.

I believe I have found $A_1 =
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$, $A_2 =
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$,  and $A_3 =
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
-1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$,  but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vectors you found should be labeled $q_1,q_2,q_3$ instead of $A_1,A_2,A_3$.
You have
\begin{align}
    a_1 &= 1q_1+0q_2+0q_3 \\
    a_2 &= 0q_1+1q_2+0q_3 \\
    a_3 &= \frac{a_3^Tq_1}{q_1^Tq_1}q_1+\frac{a_3^Tq_2}{q_2^Tq_2}q_2+\frac{a_3^Tq_3}{q_3^Tq_3}q_3 \\
    &= \frac{3}{2}q_1+\frac{1}{2}q_2+1q_3
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
   \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2 & a_3\end{bmatrix} =
   \begin{bmatrix}q_1 & q_1 & q_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \frac{3}{2} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$